# Checkbox not showing when use CSS and BootStrap

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

When I use Chrome's developer mode to cancel the following code, checkbox is displayed normally

```
    input[type="checkbox"]{ 
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

input, select, textarea {

    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    
}
```

But when I go back to eclipse to modify the above CSS code, it seems to be completely useless, and will be changed back to the way it was before modification

Comment: so the above CSS is yours, right? it has `opacity: 0;` so it's not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following

```
<input type="checkbox" th:value="${Cart.cart_id}" name="valCartId" id="cid" style="opacity:1;appearance:checkbox;margin-right:0"/>
```